# How can I see contents of gzip file with paramiko?

Tags: python, bash, networking, gzip, paramiko

Once I connect to a remote server as follows,

```
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

I can do `sftp.listdir()` and see that there are some gzip files on the remote server, like `example.gz.2016`.  How can I access the text of this file through the sftp connection, without actually downloading the file?

Comment: That's not possible, but you can list them with the usual console commands via SSH.

Comment: Why isn't this possible?

Comment: It's not part of the SFTP protocol. You can lookup all function possible at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has two parts:

1. How to view the content of a zip file from the command line
2. How to execute remote commands and get the output using python&paramiko

**First** things first: How to list the content of a zip file on the console.
[`less` can look into zip files](https://superuser.com/questions/216617/view-files-in-zip-archive-on-linux), so in your case, executing `less example.gz.2016` should give you a list of files inside the zip archive

**Second**: how to execute commands remotely.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
# next is needed if your keys are not yet known on the client.
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(HOST_NAME, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('less ' + zipfilename)
for line in stdout.readlines():
    # here you will have your listing
    print (line)

for errline in stderr.readlines():
    # Don't forget to check the error output
    print ('***', errline)
```

Good Luck!

**EDIT**
If you need a sFTP connection to the same server, you need to get it from your ssh connection like this

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

Comment: When I try this I get the exception `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.`.  How can I fix that?

Comment: @Someone_Else: hard to tell.. are you sure your server is running ssh?

Comment: I think it is?  Doing `nmap -p22 -Pn remotehost.com` does work (although nmap -p22 remotehost.com does not, so who knows).